# convert jsonObject to arraylist

Tags: java, json

i was tring to find a solution to get lat and lng as a double

```
JSONArray arr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("hits");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
    String geoloc = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("_geoloc");
    Log.d("geoloc"," : " + geoloc);

 }
```

so what i get is this : `geoloc:  : {"lat":33.84878,"lng":-5.481698}`

What I want is something like this :

```
double lat = 33.84878;
double lng = -5.481698;
```

my question is how can i get them any help please. and thank you

Comment: What is the value of the `String` `geoloc` ? And do you have multiple geloc lines ? because if yes you can't have a UNIQUE lat and lng, or the size of `arr` is maybe 1

Comment: @john Do you use Java as programming language? Please add a tag of language do you use.

Comment: You should include an example of the input JSON. So far it looks like `_geoloc` shouldn't be parsed as a string but rather as an object, whose `lat` and `long` fields you could access.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the String geoloc to JSONObject.

For example:

```
JSONObject geolocJsonObj = (JSONObject) geoloc;
```

After you can access to lat:

```
geolocJsonObj.get("lat")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class of GeoLocation and push values into the ArrayList of that:

```
class GeoLocation {
  private double lat;
  private double long;
  GeoLocation(double nLat, double nLong) { this.lat = nLat, this.long = nLong  }
  // ... Getter and Setter methods
}
```

You can use [parseDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) in order to extract double values from the json object like this:

```
JSONArray arr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("hits");
List<GeoLocation> aGeoLocationList = new ArrayList<GeoLocation>();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
    double latVal = Double.parseDouble(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("lat"));
    double longVal = Double.parseDouble(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("long"));
    aGeoLocationList.add(new GeoLocation(latVal, longVal));
}
```